# You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name

Tags: docker

Metasploitable2

```
sudo docker run --name mymet2 -it tleemcjr/metasploitable2:latest sh -c "/bin/services.sh && bash"
```

Got a error

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name
> "/mymet2" is already in use by container
> "0a545a9ae45d56909fe081b52f8f2dcad524873ee4de8e73a816d60bad783852".
> You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
> name. See 'docker run --help'.

```
└─$ sudo docker ps -a                                                                                                           125 ⨯
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                NAMES
daa5b8f6fe52        nginx                             "/docker-entrypoint.…"   19 minutes ago      Created                    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                                   webserver
c376d4818c32        tleemcjr/metasploitable2          "sh -c '/bin/service…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                         adro
bfa436743168        tleemcjr/metasploitable2          "sh -c '/bin/service…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                         mymet1
d8ffd4cf005f        tleemcjr/metasploitable2          "sh -c '/bin/service…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                         mymet12
e33cf540d3fa        tleemcjr/metasploitable2:latest   "sh -c '/bin/service…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                         victumb-it
0ea700a7b4ed        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                46 hours ago        Created                    3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       pedantic_banach
e797fef6e719        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                46 hours ago        Created                    3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       amazing_moore
0a545a9ae45d        tleemcjr/metasploitable2:latest   "sh -c '/bin/service…"   6 days ago          Exited (255) 6 days ago                                                         mymet2
2ccb79530870        tleemcjr/metasploitable2:latest   "sh -c '/bin/service…"   8 days ago          Exited (255) 8 days ago                                                         container-name
0973852bd6f1        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      8 days ago          Created                                                                         relaxed_kapitsa
99909b81ba7a        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      8 days ago          Created                                                                         tender_clarke
91602e02f23e        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      8 days ago          Created                                                                         focused_williamson
8c0089ea4194        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         stupefied_merkle
69d2e0f9d7f7        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         friendly_hoover
a92a99cc843a        nginx                             "/docker-entrypoint.…"   9 days ago          Exited (255) 8 days ago    0.0.0.0:8084->80/tcp                                 friendly_faraday
d97573916d37        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         competent_clarke
0ef45548b679        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         busy_easley
e31e8775a826        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         dazzling_allen
975416a2318f        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         intelligent_wiles
2c0bebdce7cf        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         dazzling_sinoussi
94fb024c9fba        andresriancho/w3af:unstable       "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         silly_dhawan
94e38b655cab        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         distracted_rhodes
64e17ba671ff        andresriancho/w3af:unstable       "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         adoring_darwin
56337daabc77        andresriancho/w3af:unstable       "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Created                                                                         epic_allen
a8e734ef7ceb        andresriancho/w3af:latest         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 days ago          Exited (255) 8 days ago    22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:44444->44444/tcp                     charming_curran
c3c24c6bffea        bkimminich/juice-shop             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 days ago          Exited (255) 9 days ago    127.10.0.1:80->3000/tcp                              juiceshop
7459ffcf81b4        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Exited (255) 9 days ago    127.5.0.1:80->80/tcp, 3306/tcp                       bwapp
1b07b25e9d87        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Exited (255) 9 days ago    3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       musing_buck
89866cd6c0aa        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Exited (255) 9 days ago    3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                       jolly_fermi
1d09ed02ff6c        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         wizardly_tu
4ac43bd87da8        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         wonderful_banzai
e23377cb444c        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         reverent_kepler
87b01ea8f0f3        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         dazzling_ramanujan
e9c5a6804d4d        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Exited (255) 9 days ago    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 3306/tcp                         determined_euler
7b1566924992        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         optimistic_feistel
4033540f5371        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         gracious_bardeen
4aa2430c540f        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         crazy_lehmann
7c6a027a3ac0        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         trusting_sanderson
9d5b80900227        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         heuristic_lumiere
3939529934e1        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         musing_haibt
da614c5639b5        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         recursing_hopper
a6bb4a836ff4        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         nifty_panini
c058214b1966        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         strange_goldwasser
60b9ead9dccd        raesene/bwapp                     "/run.sh"                9 days ago          Created                                                                         kind_agnesi
1a15c15650b3        webgoat/goatandwolf               "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   10 days ago         Exited (255) 9 days ago    127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9090->9090/tcp   focused_kare
8f42abbc32ba        webgoat/goatandwolf               "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   10 days ago         Exited (255) 10 days ago   127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9090->9090/tcp   recursing_kare
21935b06de2b        webgoat/goatandwolf               "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   10 days ago         Exited (255) 10 days ago   127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9090->9090/tcp   mystifying_shamir
603f0ff34d1e        webgoat/goatandwolf               "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   10 days ago         Created                                                                         exciting_ptolemy
c75a6482c9a1        webgoat/goatandwolf               "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   10 days ago         Exited (255) 10 days ago   127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp, 127.0.0.1:9090->9090/tcp   vibrant_cori
```

What does happen and how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 18):

When a container exits, it is still in the docker system. Until you remove it, the name you gave it is taken and can't be used for another container.

You can remove stopped containers using the command

```
docker container prune
```

or if you want to clean volumes, networks etc. too, you can do

```
docker system prune
```

If you rarely need to access a stopped container, you can make it a habit to add the `--rm` flag to your `docker run` commands. Then docker will remove the container when it stops.

If you just want to remove a single container, you can do

```
docker rm mymet2
```